# Do I need female to male jumper wire because I have a jumper cable

Tags: gpio

So am going to make [this tutorial](http://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/quick-reaction-game/) since am complete newbie in circuits and electronics with my Raspberry Pi, but it said I need female to male jumper wires.

However, all I have are male jumper wires since I bought the [CanaKit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00G1PNG54).

Could I just connect the ribbon cable to pi and then use male wires to do everything else normally?

Comment: With the kit above you only need male to male jumper wires. The ribbon cable and the breadboard breakout board replace the male to female jumpers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell you would just use the ribbon cable, and then connect the wires from there, acting as if the ribbon cable was the Pi's GPIO.

As Steve Robillard said, the ribbon cable will be acting as the Male-Female wire/jumper. If you are tight on space (such as a portable project or a project where you need to connect a lot of jumpers,) then you probably will want to purchase the cables, as the ribbon cable takes up a lot of space. Instead of a 1:1 used GPIO to breadboard space, you'll have used up about a 15 by 3 area on your breadboard for the use of only a few GPIO pins.

While there are only 13x2 GPIO pins, there is overlap on the edges of the jumper's board, leading to a loss of breadboard holes.

Comment: Thanks so that means that I wont be needing the female to male jumper wires, oh well its too late since I ordered them already XD

Comment: @androidmaster Glad to have helped. However, ordering the female to male jumper wires isn't bad at all. Those can be very useful, and you really should have some of them on hand all the time, in case you need to prototype or just want to hack on a project for fun and don't need to use the full header (or need the extra space that the ribbon cable header board takes up.

Comment: Well thanks again I don't know anything about electronics so any advice is greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

(This isn't a proper answer but I don't have enough reputation to comment.)

In a pinch, a workable female wire can be made easily from a male wire by pulling the exposed wire on the end back into the plastic casing, and then the resulting hole can be used to slip over the pins on the Pi.  The connection isn't very firm but in my (admittedly limited) experience it does work.